# Adding target="blank" to links with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, hyperlink

I'm attempting to add `target="_blank"` to links on a page depending on a checkbox click.

On the javascript side I have:

```
 function newTab(v) {
      if(v.tab.checked == true) { 
        document.getElementsByTagName('a').setAttribute('target', '_blank');
      } else {
        document.getElementsByTagName('a').setAttribute('target', '_self');
      }
  } //end function
```

And on the HTML side I have:

```
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="tab" onclick="newTab(this.form)" />
    <label>Open Links In New Tab?</label>
</form>
```

`<a href="//mail.google.com">Gmail</a>`

Naturally it isn't as simple as I thought it would be, so it doesn't work.

The page contains over a dozen links so I need the checkbox to apply to all links on the page - why I used `getElementsByTagName()`.  Any help appreciated!

## EDIT:

Code that works is as follows:

```
  function newTab(f) {
    var els = document.getElementsByTagName('a'); //read anchor elements into variable
    if(f.tab.checked == true) { //If the box is checked.
      for (var i in els) {
        els[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank'); //Add 'target="blank"' to the HTML
      } 
    } else { // not checked...
      for (var i in els) {
        els[i].setAttribute('target', '_self'); //Add 'target="self" to HTML
      }
    }
  } //end function.
```

Comment: Do you know you're setting `taget` not `target`?

Comment: You have a typo error. Instead of 'target' you have wrote 'taget'

Comment: It's probably easier to implement `window.open()`, which will open a new window, or tab, instead of adding/changing attributes.

Comment: Thanks on the typo

@DavidThomas - Because I want the option able to be toggled. Maybe they don't want the links to automatically open in new windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName()` returns a nodeset. You need to iterate over it and apply the change to each one in turn. What you currently have is more like jQuery syntax, which handles this internally for you.

This would have shown up in the console. With JS issues, *always* check the console before wondering what's wrong.

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
for (var i=0, len = els.length; i<len; i++)
    els[i].setAttribute('name', 'value');
```

Also, with checkboxes use change, not click events, as someone might toggle them via the keyboard, not mouse. Lastly, you should look into handling your events centrally, not inline DOM-zero events specified in the HTML. Numerous reasons for this that are beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: I used .checked which works no matter how they check the box. Also, slight mod of your code got it to work
Thank you